# How to save alpaca json file locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova, alpacajs

I'm a newbie so please be peaceful. I have managed to write a small app with phonegap using the alpacajs form framework.

I would love to save the forms locally in the app and I really fail to do so. Right now I have managed to put all the schema and form stuff in files like form.json and schema.json read them and use them.

Is there a really simple way to do so with a javascript app using phonegap while being offline. Meaning to store the stuff locally on an tablet or smartphone? The information should be saved even when you restart the tablet/phone and/or the app.

Any ideas how to achieve that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you could look at cache manifest; https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Answer (score 1):

You could save the JSON data into an sqllite database on the device

The below link about the local storage options:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html#plugin-based-options